# Error receiving broadCast Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

When trying to test the `broadCastReceiver` with the `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`, the App crashes and `logcat` says `Error receiving broadcast Intent`. please let me know what i am missing.

**Code**:

```
public class wifi_socket_01 extends Activity {

TextView tv_conn_status;
TextView tv_conn_ssid;
TextView tv_conn_speed;
TextView tv_conn_strengt;
TextView tv_conn_ip;

EditText et_ip;
ToggleButton tobBtn_connect;
EditText et_msg;
Button btn_send;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetUpAllViews(R.layout.activity_main);
    displayWiFiStates();

    this.registerReceiver(this.myWiFiReceiver, 
            new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

private BroadcastReceiver myWiFiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_EXTRA_INFO);
        if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            displayWiFiStates();
        }
    }
};

private void SetUpAllViews(int layout) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(layout);

    tv_conn_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_conn_status);
    tv_conn_ssid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_conn_ssid);
    tv_conn_speed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_conn_speed);
    tv_conn_strengt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_conn_strength);
    tv_conn_ip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_conn_ip);
    et_ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_ip);
    tobBtn_connect = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togbtn_connect);
    et_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_msg);
    btn_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
}

protected void displayWiFiStates() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String service = Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;
    ConnectivityManager myConnManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(service);
    NetworkInfo myNetworkInfo = myConnManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo myWiFiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

    if(myNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
        tv_conn_ip.setText("IP: "+myWiFiInfo.getIpAddress());
    }else {
        tv_conn_status.setText("Disconnected");
    }
}
```

}

**LogCat**:

```
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348): Process: com.example.wifi_socket_01, PID:   
15348
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error 
receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010   
(has extras) } in com.example.wifi_socket_01.MainActivity$1@4302f638
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at 
android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:782)
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at a
ndroid.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at    
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at 
com.example.wifi_socket_01.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:48)
11-08 10:26:57.645: E/AndroidRuntime(15348):    at 
android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:772)
```

Comment: which permission are you given in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: i dont think you can retrieve networkinfo with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#EXTRA_EXTRA_INFO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead:

change your

```
NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_EXTRA_INFO);
```

to

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

from the docs:
[EXTRA_EXTRA_INFO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#EXTRA_EXTRA_INFO)

> The lookup key for a string that provides optionally supplied extra
>   information about the network state.
>
> The lookup key for a string that provides optionally supplied extra
>   information about the network state. The information may be passed up
>   from the lower networking layers, and its meaning may be specific to a
>   particular network type. Retrieve it with getStringExtra(String).
>
> Constant Value: "extraInfo"

so we found the explanation of the root of the problem, it never actually returns `networkInfo` afterall. Its all about the network state.

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. actually, now I have tried your answer and the app crashed also. what i ahve done is to comment out this line `//if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
    //displayWiFiStates();
   //}` and when i commented it out and ran the app, it did not crash with your answer is there. also when that line was commented out the app did not crash even without your answer, i mean, even with `NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_EXTRA_INFO);` still there

Comment: yes because your accessing networkInfo.getType()[which is null] that is why NPE throws.

Comment: if you debug it on line networkINfo.getType() you will see that networkInfo is null.

Comment: sorry, i cannt understand why it is null, the wifi is activated

Comment: it throws NPE because your accessing a method of a null instance.

Comment: so even if you will get the instance it wont throw NPE unless if you use the instance and its behavior , now you will get a NPE.

here example:

`Person p = null; // p having only null
p.getFirstNAme(); // throws Exception its like null.getFirstName()`

Comment: kindly please bear with me, as far as i understood, the problem now is in `NetworkInfo networkInfo` and it is null because the object `networkInfo` has not been initialised. so how can I initialize it, i know that e.g: `String s = "zxcxz";`, but how can i initialise ` networkInfo`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64531/discussion-between-spurdow-and-letsamrit).

Comment: maybe you want to check this question as well  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816657/the-network-states-do-not-change-synchronously-according-to-its-broadcastreceive

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing the correct Android permissions in the AndroidManifest:

```
 <!-- ANDROID PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, it turned out to be a null pointer inside the onReceive function, I fixed this by altering

```
    Boolean up = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
```

into

```
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean up = false;
    if(info != null && info.isConnected()){
        up = true;
    }
```

I'm also on Android N, this is happening on a service that runs on the UI thread